# Which algorithm for Scipy minimize

Tags: python, scipy, minimize

I m trying to use scipy.optimize.minimize function for a very simple test. It is for the moment a simple cosinus function ponderated with a positive or negative scalar. Of course, the result should be 0 (if the scalar is negative) or Pi (if the scalar is positive).
According to the algorithm I select, the result is correct (O or Pi as expected) or not.

I don't understand my mistake.

Thank you for your help.

Her is my code.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf8 -*-

from __future__ import division
from numpy import linspace, append, zeros, sin, cos, arctan2
from scipy.optimize import minimize
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

##### PARAMETERS #####

EZ = 8.9e-3
EK = 3.3e-5

Bmax = 5.0
Nb = 1001
ph=0.0

old=ph

##### MINIMIZATION ALGORITHM #####

algo='Nelder-Mead'
#algo='Powell'
#algo='CG'
#algo='BFGS'
#algo='Newton-CG'
#algo='L-BFGS-B'
#algo='TNC'
#algo='COBYLA'
#algo='SLSQP'
#algo='dogleg'
#algo='trust-ncg'

# Energy
def F(x,b):
    ez = -EZ*b*cos(x-ph)
    return ez

def Fx(x,b):
    return EZ*b*sin(x-ph)


def Minimisation(x,b):
    result=minimize(F, x, jac=Fx , args=(b,), method=algo)
    return result.x

##### SIMULATIONS #####

list_B=linspace(Bmax,-Bmax,Nb)

p1=zeros(2*Nb)
M1=zeros(2*Nb)

B=append(list_B,-list_B)  

id=0

for bb in B :
    new=Minimisation(old, bb)
    old = new
    p1[id]=new
    id=id+1

M1 = cos(p1-ph)

##### PLOT RESULTS #####

plt.plot(B,M1,'b')
plt.grid('on')

plt.show()
```

Comment: None of those if you are only optimizing one variable!

Comment: Thank you. You re completely right. But if I change the function and its jacobian with two variables, I obtain the same problem. I can send you the complete code which is a "more complex"

Comment: It's a broad question. But something to consider here (and always): don't just take the optimizers x, read out their status messages too! You could have also described what the different results are, for people not willing to run your code (while still having ideas about it).

Comment: Oki, thank's. If I use 'Nelder-Mead' algorithm, it works some time. With the other, the minimization always gives me 0. I am new in 'optimization'. What status need I read?

Comment: Those are different algorithms. Everything except the first two use your gradient and should obtain *local convergence*!. They also all behave the same (at first sight; did not check every alg). Nelder-Mead for example; i'm unsure about local-convergence guarantees (i don't think there are any) and therefore i would expect it could find other local/global-minima than the others. It's very broad and one should analyze the objective-function to infer the effects. (broadly spoken: all from CG to the bottom do what they guarantee: convergence to a local-minimum; Nelder-Mead analysis is harder

Comment: Yes of course. But cosinus is just a very simple trigonometric function. There is only one minimum modulus 2pi (global and local are equal if i am right, no?).

Comment: 0 should be correct if the scalar is negative and pi if the scalar is positive. For my test, pencil/paper is better than scipy ;-). My problem is that the function has not analytical solution and I don't know which algorithm select.

Comment: Your function is not convex (local-minimum not necessarily global-minimum) and in this case local-convergence hurts. This might change with bound-constraints, but i'm not going to check it (question still too informal and code a bit bloated).